# How to use Django xml parser?

Tags: python, django, xml, serialization, django-rest-framework

I've got a Django endpoint to which I want to send a quite complicated/nested XML. For this I'm trying to use the [django-rest-framework-xml package](https://github.com/jpadilla/django-rest-framework-xml). I created the following viewset:

```
class RecordViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Publication.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PublicationSerializer
    serializer_detail_class = PublicationSerializer
    parser_classes = (XMLParser,)
    renderer_classes = (XMLRenderer,)

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print(type(request.data))
        print(request.data)
        return Response("", status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

In the create() method it first prints out "str" and then the raw xml I'm receiving. It hasn't been converted to a dict or anything else. I'm a missing something here? Shouldn't it have at least been parsed to something else than a raw string?

Also; since the XML has quite a complex structure I need to reshuffle some fields in order to shape it into my models. What would be the place to do such a thing?